# Iterate thru array of object in array

Tags: javascript

I have next data:

```
const someArr = [
[{id:1, value: 'test1'}, {id:2, value: 'test2'}],
[{id:3, value: 'test3'}, {id:4, value: 'test4'}],
[{id:5, value: 'test5'}, {id:6, value: 'test6'}]
];
```

What is the best way to iterate thru this and get each id and value? Use map() inside map()?

```
someArr.map(items => items.map(item => console.log(item)));
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten structure and then iterate over your data.

```js
const someArr = [
[{id:1, value: 'test1'}, {id:2, value: 'test2'}],
[{id:3, value: 'test3'}, {id:4, value: 'test4'}],
[{id:5, value: 'test5'}, {id:6, value: 'test6'}]
];

someArr.flatMap(x => x).forEach(x => console.log(x))
```